# Improve description of tag wikis in Help Center

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-wiki, help-center, help-center-proposed

The Help Center articles on the ["approve tag wiki edits" privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) and ["trusted user" privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) state:

> #### What are tag wikis?
>
> Tag wikis are a general introduction to a topic defined by that tag. They're a place to consolidate and form a sub-community around a tag. They contain, among other things, frequently asked questions in the tag, top users in the tag, and best recent answers in the tag.

---

Let's break this down:

> Tag wikis are a general introduction to a topic defined by that tag.

OK, makes sense.

> They're a place to consolidate and form a sub-community around a tag.

There's not much community building going on there, I guess, but I can see where this is coming from.

> They contain, among other things, frequently asked questions in the tag,

Yep, some tag wikis contain those, and that's definitely something that belongs in there.

> top users in the tag, and best recent answers in the tag.

Err ... no? Those lists aren't part of the tag wiki, they're shown on the tag *information* page just like the tag wiki. It's not something we want people to edit into the tag wiki.

---

My proposal is to replace this section with something like what's shown when [creating a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/4551):

> A tag wiki is a detailed introduction to the topic, ideally about one page long, suitable as a destination for those curious about it. It may contain, among other things, information about what questions should have this tag, some basic definitions, a brief introduction to the subject and important links for learning more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We reviewed your suggestion and agreed. We have updated the help center articles as suggested to reflect it.